# Is the 2 GetLogicalDrives API in pywin32 the same?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

I find there are two GetLogicalDrives APIs in pywin32, one in win32api module, the other in win32file. The description of both seems the same. Is there any difference between them? And I read some codes, it seems that most people use win32file.GetLogicalDrives instead of the other. Could anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1):

They're basically the same. They both call `kernel32!GetLogicalDrives`. The win32api version is a bit simpler since it builds the result directly by calling `PyLong_FromLong` (Python 3), while the win32file version calls `Py_BuildValue`. They both return just the integer bitmask, so there's no intrinsic reason to prefer either over the other. Use whichever is more convenient. For example, if you're using win32api, don't import win32file just to call `win32file.GetLogicalDrives`.

cdb debug session:

**win32api**

```
>>> win32api.GetLogicalDrives() 
Breakpoint 0 hit
kernel32!GetLogicalDrives:
00000000`772bae00 4883ec68        sub     rsp,68h
0:000> k5
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0030f2d8 00000000`670a2735 kernel32!GetLogicalDrives
00000000`0030f2e0 00000000`5ffaf8bd win32api+0x2735
00000000`0030f310 00000000`6002385b python34!PyCFunction_Call+0x12d
00000000`0030f340 00000000`60025c89 python34!call_function+0x2ab
00000000`0030f3a0 00000000`6002770c python34!PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2279
0:000> bl
 0 e 00000000`772bae00     0001 (0001)  0:**** kernel32!GetLogicalDrives
 1 d 00000000`5ffa1450     0001 (0001)  0:**** python34!PyLong_FromLong
0:000> be1; g; bd1; k5
Breakpoint 1 hit
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0030f308 00000000`5ffaf8bd python34!PyLong_FromLong
00000000`0030f310 00000000`6002385b python34!PyCFunction_Call+0x12d
00000000`0030f340 00000000`60025c89 python34!call_function+0x2ab
00000000`0030f3a0 00000000`6002770c python34!PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2279
00000000`0030f4a0 00000000`60027aae python34!PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x65c
```

**win32file**

```
>>> win32file.GetLogicalDrives()
Breakpoint 0 hit
kernel32!GetLogicalDrives:
00000000`772bae00 4883ec68        sub     rsp,68h
0:000> k5
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0030f2d8 00000000`6704c855 kernel32!GetLogicalDrives
00000000`0030f2e0 00000000`5ffaf8bd win32file+0xc855
00000000`0030f310 00000000`6002385b python34!PyCFunction_Call+0x12d
00000000`0030f340 00000000`60025c89 python34!call_function+0x2ab
00000000`0030f3a0 00000000`6002770c python34!PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2279
0:000> be1; g; bd1; k5
Breakpoint 1 hit
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0030f298 00000000`60046184 python34!PyLong_FromLong
00000000`0030f2a0 00000000`600461f5 python34!va_build_value+0x64
00000000`0030f2e0 00000000`5ffaf8bd python34!Py_BuildValue+0x25
00000000`0030f310 00000000`6002385b python34!PyCFunction_Call+0x12d
00000000`0030f340 00000000`60025c89 python34!call_function+0x2ab
```

Sorry about `win32api+0x2735` and `win32file+0xc855`. I don't have the debug symbols for PyWin32. I pip-installed the wheel from [pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32).